# AngularJS 1.4.8 $injector:Modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, angularjs-injector

I am relatively new to AngularJS and am getting an "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]". In addition, I am getting several syntax errors on the first line of various js files.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh9Wd.png)

[error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=userApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DuserApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:24:186%0A%20%20%20%20at%20b%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:23:251)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:23:494%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:38:117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:7:333)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:37:488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:41:249)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js:19:463)

I can't seem to remedy the situation, any thoughts?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>User CRM</title>

  <!-- FOR ANGULAR ROUTING -->
  <base href="/">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <!-- load bootstrap from CDN and custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/assets/css/style.css">

  <!-- JS -->
  <!-- load angular and angular-route via CDN -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>

  <!-- controllers -->
  <script src="public/app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="public/app/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script>

  <!-- services -->
  <script src="public/app/services/authService.js"></script>
  <script src="public/app/services/userService.js"></script>

  <!-- main Angular app files -->
  <script src="public/app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="public/app/app.routes.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">

  <!-- NAVBAR -->
  <header>

    <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse" ng-if="main.loggedIn">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire text-danger"></span> User CRM</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/users"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Users</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li ng-if="!main.loggedIn"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
          <li ng-if="main.loggedIn" class="navbar-text">Hello {{ main.user.name }}!</li>
          <li ng-if="main.loggedIn"><a href="#" ng-click="main.doLogout()">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>

  <main class="container">
    <!-- ANGULAR VIEWS -->
    <div ng-view></div>
  </main>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('userApp', [
  'ngAnimate', // add animations to our Angular Directives
  'app.routes', // routing for our application
  'authService', // service file
  'mainCtrl', // main view controller
  'userCtrl', // controller for user management pages
  'userService' //service file
]);
```

app.routes.js

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  // home page route
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/home.html'
  })

  // login page
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/login.html',
    controller: 'mainController',
    controllerAs: 'login'
  })

  // get rid of the hash in the URL
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

Comment: You need to update `angular-animate` to version 1.4.8 . Because you are using Angular 1.4.8.

Comment: didn't make a difference, the error seems to be coming from the angular.min.js file

Comment: Think you need to make a plunker for anyone to help you here.  Try cut and pasting:  `<!-- main Angular app files -->
  <script src="public/app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="public/app/app.routes.js"></script>`  Above where you load the controllers.

Comment: Also, you don't inject any controller or service in the app.'s file.

Comment: @DaveM tried that, didn't make a difference moving the main angular app files above where I am loading the controllers.

Comment: The errors in that screenshot `Unexpected token '<'` are an indication that you aren't getting the correct JavaScript files delivered.  Usually this happens when you have your server delivering `index.html` for all requests, causing requests for your JavaScript assets to return `index.html` instead, which has `<` as the first character in the file.

Comment: essentially, I think your problem is probably with how your server is configured to handle html5Mode.

Comment: @Claies the error ended up being an undefined "userApp" due to undefined dependencies.

Comment: @NickCarroll Did you ever figure this out?  If not, if you make a plunker, I'll try to help.

Comment: @DaveM I was able to chase the error down to a typo in one of the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try using an updated version of the angular-animate module.

The [AngularJS documentation for v1.4.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ngAnimate) suggests a few options if you're loading the scripts through a CDN. For example, try this one: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js

Comment: I updated the angular-animate module. The error seems to be with the angular.min.js module.

Comment: Yeah, I saw someone else posted about a minute before I did, heh. I

Comment: Can you expand the error message that's coming from angular.min.js so that we can see the stacktrace? The error messages coming from the other files seems like something's messed up with the HTML potentially

Comment: Is this hosted on a local or remote server? It's possible there could be an issue with your webserver and your javascript files for your controllers/services aren't being loaded. Try accessing one of those files from within your browser (http://my_server.local/public/app/controllers/MainCtrl.js) and make sure it loads properly in the browser. The "unexpected input '<'" is usually from there either being extra html tags in your html page (I don't see any) or the file that is supposed to be a javascript file has HTML contents somehow.

Comment: the files are hosted on a local server. Tried opening them this way, everything loaded properly from what I could tell.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the angular.js module instead of the minified version to get a more verbose error message and got the error notification that userApp was not defined. It turns out the issue lied in the other dependencies not being properly defined. So, I removed all dependencies but ngAnimate and app.routes as well as removing the ng-controller "mainController as main" from the index.html file. This seems to have solved the problem, however, now I need to find my error in the mainCtrl.js file so I can use the mainController.

Thanks for the help!